# wpf splitter toggle orientation

Tags: c#, wpf

I know how to do this in winforms but it doesn't appear as easy in wpf. How can i make it possible to toggle the orientation (vertical/horizontal) when using the splitter in wpf? I was trying to create a simple example of just a button switching the toggle.

In winforms I'd put something like this in the toggle button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            splitContainer1.Orientation = splitContainer1.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical ? Orientation.Horizontal : Orientation.Vertical; 
        }
```

In wpf I got this far as there is no orientation property to the splitter....?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Panels.GridSplitterHorizontalSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="GridSplitterHorizontalSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Top</TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Bottom</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: neither of the attempts below appear to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2 / Edit 3**

I'm not really happy with this solution, since you effectively define both views instead of reusing one definition and just changing a property, but maybe it helps you in understanding possible solutions.

*I updated the XAML to show, how the content areas can be separated from the grid layout and how values can be propagated through the ContentPresenters*

In XAML, define the desired views as resources and use `ContentControl` to select a template:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="content1">
            <Label Content="{Binding}" Background="Yellow"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="content2">
            <Label Content="Content Part 2"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="gridHorizontal">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource content1}"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource content2}"/>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="gridVertical">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding}" />
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource content2}"/>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Transform" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl1" DataContext="Hello World" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=gridVertical}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

In Code Behind, change the template on button click:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (contentControl1.Template == Resources["gridVertical"])
            contentControl1.Template = (ControlTemplate)Resources["gridHorizontal"];
        else
            contentControl1.Template = (ControlTemplate)Resources["gridVertical"];
    }
```

**Edit**

Have a look at the `ResizeDirection` property.

**Original**

I have no definite source, but my experiments show, that the splitter always works in direction of its long border.

So a Width=10, Height=9 Splitter would work as a up/down splitter while Width=9, Height=10 Splitter would work as left/right splitter.

A sample to play with:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Upper Left"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Upper Right"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Lower Left"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="Lower Right"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

At start, the red splitter is useless, since it tries to provide a functionality it cant fulfill, but as soon as the yellow splitter is pulled down a bit, the red splitter converts to a left/right splitter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is a cool idea, and seems to work well, i know you mentioned it's not idea, but what really would be, i think it works good.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Panels.GridSplitterHorizontalSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="GridSplitterHorizontalSample" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Top</TextBlock>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Vertical" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Bottom</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

you can try something like this
note the ResizeDirection property in the GridSplitter object

Comment: what version of .net are you using. it says that property is not valid.

Comment: i updated the post to be more clear on what im trying to do.